# how to change php code to MVC codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","apmsetup");
mysql_select_db("test");
session_start();   


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){


$id=addslashes($_POST['id']); 
$pw=addslashes($_POST['pw']); 

$sql="SELECT id FROM appuser WHERE id='$id' and pw='$pw'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);



if($count==1)   
{
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$id;  
}
}
if(!$_SESSION['login_user']){
echo "<script>";
echo 'alert("login");';
echo 'document.location.replace("/Login/Login_screen.php");';
echo "</script>";
}else{}?>
```

above is my php code.

i want it to change codeigniter

but i have no ideas about CI.

please help 
above is my php code.

i want it to change codeigniter

but i have no ideas about CI.

please help

Comment: "but i have no ideas about CI." - well, probably the best framework documentation ever... http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html

Answer (score 1):

As you are beginner and i think you very well know OOP concepts.
MVC in nutshell.

MVC - Model -where mainly query part comes.
      View-template which  client sees.
      controller-are where your request is routed to, and will call models and or views.

model and controller both have class whose  name[first alphabet] will be in captial letter these will extend CI_Model and CI_Controller class of Codeigniter.

so if you want to change above code in to MVC pattern then you have to create 3 files which will be in model,controller and view folder of CI framework.

Further to learn how to create those you can see various tutorials on internet.

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * News home page, found at /news
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'News home page';
    }

}



class News_m extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Define the table name
     */
    private $_table = 'news';

    /**
     * Read all news items
     */
    public function read()
    {

        // Return an associative array of all news items
        return $this->db
            ->get($this->_table)
            ->result_array();

    }

}
```

Changing your code to MVC is that much  easy you have to do lot of things like database settings,routing,creating .htacess file,etc So this will be fun and start the journey.No one On SO will change your Code to MVC on guidlines will be provided.

Further a link for you can start from here 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html

Site note: Don't use mysql_ they are depriated and will be removed from PHP-7